# Entity Framework get count of distinct items

Tags: c#, sql, entity-framework, linq

I have a table in my database that looks like this:

```
ID      value     channel
_________________________
1         50         201
2         55         201
3         60         201
4         10         202
5         12         202
```

And I want to get a count for the number of distinct channel values. So, in this case that count would be 2.

I am using visual C# with the Entity Framework.

Sorry if this is a simple question, but I couldn't find anything after googling.

Thanks for any help.

Comment: So... what did you actually try? Please at least add the code you have so far (models, context initialization, query attempts...)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use [`Distinct()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb348436(v=vs.110).aspx) followed by [`Count()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.linq.enumerable.count(v=vs.110).aspx), like this:

```
int count = data.Select(d => d.channel).Distinct().Count();
```

Comment: Thanks! This worked. Just for my understanding, what does `d => d.channel` do?

Comment: @RyanHosford `(d => d.channel)` inside `Select` tells LINQ which field to take. It's the same as running a `SELECT channel FROM data` in SQL.